# Issues with owning publicly-traded stock of certain companies and deriving benefit from it?

Tags: money, business, issurei-hanaa

Is it prohibited to own publicly-traded stock in a company that owns and runs restaurants that sell cheeseburgers and/or other foods where the meat and milk is mixed together while cooking or owns chametz on Pesach? Or would the ownership of publicly-traded stock not constitute halachic ownership or deriving benefit or is there some other rationale for it not being prohibited?